# run hibernate-tools-maven-plugins, return invalid override definition: Element type "hibernate-reverse-engineering" must be declared

Tags: hibernate, maven, hibernate-tools

My pom.xml is as follow:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Test</groupId>
  <artifactId>Hibernate_Reveng_Maven</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Hibernate Reveng Gen Java</name>
  
  <properties>
      <project.basedir>C:/Kei/SLIS_git_eclipse_2023_09_20231115_2/Hibernate_Reveng (Not work) </project.basedir>
    <h2.version>1.4.200</h2.version>   
    
  </properties>
  
  <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>           
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.29.Final</version>         
            <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>entity-generation</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>hbm2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <ejb3>true</ejb3>
                      <revengFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/reveng.xml</revengFile>
                    </configuration>
                  </execution>                
        </executions>   
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
                <version>12.2.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>     
      </plugin>      
      </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.29.Final</version>
        </dependency>           
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc14 -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <version>12.2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My hibernate.properties is as follow and is placed in src/main/resources:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
#hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.9.xxx.xx:25100:dsli01.xxxxx.com
hibernate.connection.username=dsli01
hibernate.connection.password=xxxxxx
```

My reveng.xml is placed in src/main/resources and is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC 
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" 
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <!-- This assumes your database connection is pointing to the proper catalog -->
  <!-- To get all tables in the named schema, use the following 
       <schema-selection match-schema="PM" />
  -->
  <!--  to get only the named tables -->
  <schema-selection match-schema="dsli01" match-table="UAC_USER_SSN"/>
  
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

then when I run mvn clean install, the following error is shown:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal [32morg.hibernate:hibernate-tools-maven-plugin:5.4.29.Final:hbm2java[m [1m(entity-generation)[m on project [36mHibernate_Reveng_Maven[m: [1;31mExecution entity-generation of goal org.hibernate:hibernate-tools-maven-plugin:5.4.29.Final:hbm2java failed: Could not configure overrides from file: C:\Kei\SLIS_git_eclipse_2023_09_20231115_2\Hibernate_Reveng (Not work)\src\main\resources\reveng.xml[m: invalid override definition: Element type "hibernate-reverse-engineering" must be declared. -> [1m[Help 1][m
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the [1m-e[m switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the [1m-X[m switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [1m[Help 1][m http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

what is the error means? And I see my reveng.xml has element

```
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
........
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Answer (score 0):

Capricorn1 answer in [Hibernate mapping recently failing with SAX parser exception: element "hibernate-mapping" must be declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56838096/hibernate-mapping-recently-failing-with-sax-parser-exception-element-hibernate) solved my problem. That is, modify the DOCTYPE in the hibernate.reveng.xml file.

Anyway, What is the origin problem come from and why above can fix the issue is unknown yet.